# Using regular expressions to compare array elements inside switch statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm building a basic 'hangman' game for my wife's history class. To that end, I've created a class that creates the 'gameWord' in both the string and array formats.

Within that class, I would like to also create another array that faces the player and changes based on their input. That array should show a '*' for each letter and a '_' for each space.

I've tried using regex in if or switch statements while iterating through the gameWord array with no luck. Here's one of my basic attempts:

```
class GameWord {
  constructor(word) {
    if ( word.length <= 3 )
      return console.error('Error: Your word must be at least three letters long');

      this.word = word.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, ''); 
      this.wordUserView = this.word.toProperCase( );
      this.wordSet = this.wordUserView.split('');

    const len = this.wordSet.length;
    var i = 0;

    this.wordSetHidden = [];
    for ( ; i <= len; i++) {
      if (this.wordSet[i] == /[a-zA-Z]/g) {
    this.wordSetHidden.push("*");
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Here is another example of something I've tried:

```
var reAlpha = /[a-zA-Z]/;
var reSpace = /\s/;
var arr = ["W", "i", "n", "s", "t", "o", "n", " ", "1", 2, 0];
var newArr = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  switch (arr) {
    case reAlpha.match:
      newArr.push(arr[i] = "*");
    case reSpace.match:
      newArr.push(arr[i] = "_");
    break;
  default: console.log("No matches")
  };
}
```

What I get is 'No matches' of course, because a direct comparision isn't being made to the elements in the array. However, when I try to do something like element.match(arr), I get that match isn't a function, I guess because it's reading the element as an object and not a string?

I understand I could use CSS to hide individual letters, but I want to have the game logic work on the back end. Students could easily alter the css to get the answers.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the word as a string, you can use a `replace` statement with regex to replace the characters with '*' and spaces with '_':

```
var word = "Winston 120";
var wordToDisplay = word.replace(/[^\s]/g, '*').replace(/[\s]/g,'_');
```

If you have the word as an array, you could do an `if` statement in your loop:

```
var arr = ["W", "i", "n", "s", "t", "o", "n", " ", "1", 2, 0];
var newArr = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if(/[^\s]/.test(arr[i])){
    newArr.push(arr[i] = "*");
  } else {
    newArr.push(arr[i] = "_");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I modified my first code example to use test and had the class push into a wordSetHidden array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an if statement in this case.

If you want to use a switch

```
var reAlpha = /[a-zA-Z]/;
var reSpace = /\s/;
var arr = ["W", "i", "n", "s", "t", "o", "n", " ", "1", 2, 0];
var newArr = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  switch (true) {
    case reAlpha.test(arr[i]):
      newArr.push(arr[i] = "*");
    case reSpace.test(arr[i]):
      newArr.push(arr[i] = "_");
    break;
      default: console.log("No matches");
  };
}
```

If

```
var reAlpha = /[a-zA-Z]/;
var reSpace = /\s/;
var arr = ["W", "i", "n", "s", "t", "o", "n", " ", "1", 2, 0];
var newArr = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if (reAlpha.test(arr[i]) {
    newArr.push(arr[i] = "*");
  } else if (reSpace.test(arr[i])) {
    newArr.push(arr[i] = "_");
  } else {
    console.log("No matches");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I wasnt aware of the ‘test’ method. Thank you!